# C# Bitmap.Save path

Tags: c#, path, bitmap

I have a bitmap 'b' and this line is getting me a problem

```
b.Save(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\result\\img.jpg");
```

The software breaks at that line.
It is because of the path because when i use this line it works, the bitmap is saved:

```
b.Save(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("C:\\img.jpg");
```

Why is the first line not working? I can't get what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change that to

`b.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\img.jpg");`

The problem here is that `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase` doesn't return the executable directory as you might have wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want show the image on the web browser yo can use the outputstream of the Response class, or even use one of the stream on the System.IO nameSpace.

```
b.Save(Response.OutputStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```